# Specify print area InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, export

[image: A1 document. Red rectangle represents desired section to export to pdf.]

I'm having trouble specifying a print area for a document in InDesign:

The document size is A1, yet I want to print a specific section in A3 paper. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: I understand the question, but I don't understand the image?

Answer (score 1):

First drag the [zero point](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/rulers-measurement-units.html#change_the_zero_point) of your rulers to the top left of the area you want to print.

Then open the print dialog and under the *Setup* tab, check *Tile* and select *Manual*. You can see in the preview on the left that the printed page (the smaller rectangle) is positioned on your document (the larger rectangle) at the zero point of your rulers.

[image]

Comment: Oh. My. God.
You just solved a problem that has been bugging me for years and that I thought had no solution. I often needed to print a specific area and I had NO idea that you could move the zero point for that. Great, thanks!

Comment: Okey, thank you. Thought there would be a more intuitive way where you could move the print area through the document to know exactly whats going to be printed. This methods is pretty inaccurate I think, and you dont get a preview of whats gonna get printed

Comment: How is it inaccurate? You define the exact point you want to print from. Just draw a rectangle the same size as your paper, place it where you need and drag your zero point to the corner of the box.